# Using NUnit to test a list of items

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, moq

Tell me if my concept is wrong. I have 2 classes; `Country` and `State`. A state will have a `CountryId` property.

I have a service and a repository as follows:

Service.cs

```
    public LazyList<State> GetStatesInCountry(int countryId)
    {
        return new LazyList<State>(geographicsRepository.GetStates().Where(s => s.CountryId == countryId));
    }
```

IRepository.cs

```
public interface IGeographicRepository
{
    IQueryable<Country> GetCountries();

    Country SaveCountry(Country country);

    IQueryable<State> GetStates();

    State SaveState(State state);
}
```

MyTest.cs

```
    private IQueryable<State> getStates()
    {
        List<State> states = new List<State>();
        states.Add(new State(1, 1, "Manchester"));//params are: StateId, CountryId and StateName
        states.Add(new State(2, 1, "St. Elizabeth"));
        states.Add(new State(2, 2, "St. Lucy"));
        return states.AsQueryable();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Can_Get_List_Of_States_In_Country()
    {

        const int countryId = 1;
        //Setup
        geographicsRepository.Setup(x => x.GetStates()).Returns(getStates());

        //Call
        var states = geoService.GetStatesInCountry(countryId);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsInstanceOf<LazyList<State>>(states);
        //How do I write an Assert here to check that the states returned has CountryId = countryId?
        geographicsRepository.VerifyAll();
    }
```

I need to verify the information of the states returned. Do I need to write a loop and put the asserts in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is something in nunit for this, but you could do this with linq:

```
    states.All(c => Assert.AreEqual(1, c.CountryId))
```

**EDIT**
after quick googling it seems you can do this

```
Assert.That(states.Select(c => c.CountryId), Is.All.EqualTo(1));
```

Comment: Its not valid LINQ. Its telling me that the Assert should return a boolean.

Answer (score 3):

Assert.IsTrue(states.All(x => 1 == x.CountryId));